# List/Num: Means results in argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r

I made a list of 100 numbers from 100 permutations using the following code:

```
for(i in 3:length(GeneData)) {
  # Grab the 37 observations in the gene
  for(j in 1:37) {
    genePerm[j] <- GeneData[j, i]
  } 

  # 100 permutations
  for(k in 1:100) {
    genePerm <- sample(genePerm)
    newA <- vector()
    newB <- vector()
    # 23 GeneA, 14 GeneB
    for(l in 1:37) {
      if(l < 24) {
        newA[l] <- genePerm[l]
      } else {
        newB[l - 23] <- genePerm[l]
      }
    }

    testChair[k] <- t.test(newA, newB)$p.value

  }

  permPValues[i - 2] <- mean(testChair)
}
```

The dataset is 1144 genes, each with 37 observations. So the goal was to run a for loop over every gene (3:1147), then grab all observations 1:37, put them in a random sample of A/B of respective sizes above. Grab the P-Value from the t.test of each, and then run this permutation 100x. I wanted to then save the mean of those P-Values in the last statement before running the next gene.

When I run this, I get over 50 warnings(): "In mean.default(testChair) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

```
class(testChair)
[1] "list"
str(testChair)
List of 100 num
```

A small example of data:

```
Patient Class   1405_i_at   200030_s_at 200062_s_at
1   A   7.492258127 12.45140014 13.48393678
2   A   7.899176081 12.5622002  13.5087836
3   A   8.668834124 11.84527253 13.04315946
4   A   9.91313519  12.04905336 13.42893925
5   A   6.047972634 12.77472603 13.63448007
6   A   8.368976147 12.24842422 13.41529093
7   A   7.20836421  12.93198614 13.13948227
8   A   7.919268023 12.28964756 13.2397595
9   A   9.003944903 11.68261433 13.08924549
10  A   8.084666646 12.18271975 13.41492561
11  A   9.840143746 12.34283432 12.96360228
12  A   6.99033759  12.57560342 13.2587594
13  A   7.978610388 12.54610449 13.1813085
14  A   8.747926877 11.8624978  13.24270026
15  A   9.486237216 12.01866821 13.33474933
16  A   8.760956899 12.49961585 13.65201122
17  A   8.382102061 12.04592178 13.39857364
18  A   8.073885916 12.3062644  13.76705502
19  A   9.412851349 12.39448144 13.16896019
20  A   8.364735507 12.42232335 13.33859203
21  A   9.157396203 12.09875546 13.27433327
22  A   5.913420688 12.2529661  13.62515813
23  A   7.162806841 11.99874653 13.36516341
24  B   8.734138362 12.17417605 13.43827062
25  B   6.785358473 11.98805352 13.44471807
26  B   7.252916328 12.57831463 13.29748783
27  B   8.988631789 11.9242628  13.88455123
28  B   8.36856432  11.84448206 13.22715915
29  B   6.430597552 12.26866611 13.35831894
30  B   7.092622736 11.86263629 13.22220515
31  B   6.708408743 11.77572547 13.4647575
32  B   6.700810798 11.80986457 13.52356174
33  B   7.032134704 12.25581888 13.34332883
34  B   7.731854575 12.13688324 13.3219734
35  B   7.71243075  11.92484732 13.13499252
36  B   6.293368361 12.07172977 13.39202083
37  B   7.992184287 12.2412432  13.33908972
```

Comment: You should consider to share a _minimal reproducible_ example.

Comment: Best way to upload a dataset @markus ?

Comment: Use `dput`. Include everything necessary so others are able to run your code. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some guidance.

Comment: @markus Added data in text form, top row is header

Comment: I suppose you shared `GeneData`. But what about `genePerm` and `testChair`? Are those emtpy vectors?

Comment: Yes, sorry - declared in code above. Empty vectors.

Comment: It looks like you are investigating differential gene expression? In which case, I strongly recommend learning the [limma](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) package in Bioconductor. It handles a lot of the issues (such as correcting for multiple testing), so that you don't have to.

Comment: @neilfws honestly no idea what we're doing. It's just an example for using multiple testing. Not allowed to use packages, thus why I'm manually trying to do it. I'm lacking comprehension on why I can't run the mean on numbers... Lol